# Does Swift have constructs for parallel programming through Grand Central Dispatch's dispatch_async?

Tags: parallel-processing, grand-central-dispatch, swift

I am interested in adopting the new Swift programming language. The code base I maintain makes extensive use of multi-core processing through the C++ Grand Central Dispatch extensions (dispatch_async, etc.)

Does anyone who has reviewed Swift as it stands know if this language has the ability to access GCD in a fashion similar to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it does though I have not had too much success in the playground. In a real project it should work. All of the iOS 8 and OS X 10.10 documentation show Swift syntax for GCD methods.

I am using `dispatch_once` for singletons in my current project, it works just fine:

`NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` both use GCD under the hood, and it seems to work better in the playground:

```
let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()

for index in 1...20
{
    operationQueue.addOperationWithBlock(
    {
        let thread = NSThread.currentThread()
        let threadNumber = thread.valueForKeyPath("private.seqNum").integerValue

        println("Task #\(index) completed on thread #\(threadNumber)")
    })
}
```

Output:

```
Task #1 completed on thread #3
Task #2 completed on thread #4
Task #3 completed on thread #5
Task #4 completed on thread #4
Task #5 completed on thread #5
Task #6 completed on thread #3
Task #7 completed on thread #6
Task #8 completed on thread #4
Task #9 completed on thread #5
Task #10 completed on thread #5
Task #11 completed on thread #3
Task #12 completed on thread #6
Task #13 completed on thread #3
Task #14 completed on thread #3
Task #15 completed on thread #6
Task #16 completed on thread #5
Task #17 completed on thread #4
Task #18 completed on thread #3
Task #19 completed on thread #4
Task #20 completed on thread #3
```

Comment: To be fair, this functionality is exposed via the Foundation library and isn't native to the Swift language.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with them in swift, but it appears that GCD's functions are available with Swift.

Comment: Excellent, that sounds like a positive enough lead that I'll give it a try.  Thanks!